# Java - JSONObject Parsing only 1 string?

Tags: java, json

I'm fairly new to JSON parsing in Java but when I try and parse this JSON String & find out it's "ID", it repeats the same one twice.

```
[
  {"id":"{ID1}","time":123},
  {"id":"{ID2}","time":124}
]
```

This is my Java code:

```
        // v = json string, c = "id"
        String output = v.replace("[", "").replace("]", "");  
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(output);
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i = 0 ; i < obj.length(); i++){
            System.out.println(obj.getString(c));
            list.add(obj.getString(c));
        }

        return list.get(1);
```

it returns ID1 twice or more. Please help

Comment: the json is an array, do not remove the array notation (i.e. the '[' and the ']')

Comment: so keep that there & keep as is?

Comment: Where in your loop do you use the loop index `i`?  How would one know which array element to reference?

Comment: @DwB wont that give me "A JSONObject text must begin with '{'" error?

Comment: Why do you remove `[]`, when they are what identifies a JSON array?

Comment: @HotLicks c = "id" in json string.

Comment: Go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  It only takes 5-10 minutes to learn.

Comment: (There's no way the above code will even come close to working.)

Comment: I didn't ask for criticism & I did state I am new to JSON Parsing in Java.

Comment: Go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  (And beware of a lot of Java JSON "tutorials" which were written by folks who don't really understand JSON.)

Comment: (Especially stay away from tutorials that mention "POJOs" right off.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my code by using it as a JSONArray(Thanks @HotLicks)

```
JSONArray obj = new JSONArray(v);
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

            for(int i = 0 ; i < obj.length(); i++){
                Logger.WriteOutput(obj.getJSONObject(i).getString(c), Logger.LogLevel.Info);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON represents an array - so that's how you should parse it. You can then easily get the `id` property from each `JSONObject` within the array. For example:

```
import org.json.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
        String json = 
            "[{\"id\":\"{ID1}\",\"time\":123}, {\"id\":\"{ID2}\",\"time\":124}]";
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(json);

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject o = array.getJSONObject(i);
            System.out.println(o.getString("id"));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{ID1}
{ID2}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
// This line is useless
// String output = v.replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(output);
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i = 0 ; i < arr.length(); i++){
    System.out.println(arr.getJSONObject(i).getString(c));
    list.add(arr.getJSONObject(i).getString(c));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a java bean for your json (for example [here](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)):

```
public class Item {

    @JsonProperty("id")
    private String  id;
    @JsonProperty("time")
    private Integer time;

    public final String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public final void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public final Integer getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public final void setTime(Integer time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

}
```

If you are using Jackson Java JSON-processor, you can create a List from JSON-String this way:

```
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    try {
        List<Item> items = objectMapper.readValue(
                    yourJSONString, 
                    objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, Item.class));

        for (Item item : items) {
            System.out.println(item.getId());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: There's absolutely no need to create a bean here.

Comment: @JonSkeet matter of taste

Comment: It looks like considerably more effort to me, for the given task. (In other cases it's very appropriate of course - but compare the amount of code you've provided for an *incomplete* program with my shorter code which is a self-contained program with the same output.)

Comment: @JonSkeet i believe OP wants (perhaps later) more that just getting ID. I tryed to provide an universal OO solution

Comment: Given that the OP is returning from the method with just an ID, and they describe their attempt to "find out its ID" I think this is overengineering for the problem described. Of course they *may* want more later - at which point it would be appropriate. But while there's a simpler solution, I think it's reasonable to present that instead :)

Answer (score -1):

use below code

```
String v = "[{\"id\":\"ID1\",\"time\":123},{\"id\":\"ID2\",\"time\":124}]";
        String c = "id";
        JSONArray obj = null;
        try {
            obj = new JSONArray(v);

            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (int i = 0; i < obj.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject j = (JSONObject) obj.get(i);
                System.out.println(j.getString(c));
                list.add(j.getString(c));
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

note that i have slightly corrected the json structure too

**before**
    [
      {"id":"{ID1}","time":123},
      {"id":"{ID2}","time":124}
    ]

**after**
    [
      {"id":"ID1","time":123},
      {"id":"ID2","time":124}
    ]

Comment: Having `"{ID1}"` does **not** make the JSON invalid.

Comment: you are right - if he purposefully considered to have "{ID1}" as string. Since he is fairly new to JSON, and his post talks about just returning ID1(not with curly brackets), I have  modified the input string.